# Swift AV Player Video Should be AspectFill OR Full Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

At Sign In Screen I've to display background video with full resolution. I'm able to do this by double tapping on below image at black area.

[image]

Here is my required result. but this isn't done by coding. I just did this by double tapping on black area. 
[image]

Here is my Code for this class.

```
class loginViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
let player = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    let myFileManager = FileManager.default
    let mainBundle = Bundle.main
    let resourcesPath = mainBundle.resourcePath!
    guard let allItemsInTheBundle = try? myFileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: resourcesPath) else {
        return
        }

    let videoName = "login_video"
    let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mp4")
    let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath!)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        let controller=AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player=player

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)        
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill;

        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
        videoView.addSubview(controller.view)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        player.play()
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        loopVideo(player: player)
}
func loopVideo(player: AVPlayer) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        player.play()
    }
}   
}
```

can anyone suggest me that how can I achieve this required result. I found this solution but in vein.

```
     let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)        
     playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill;
```

Please suggest me the better way. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code does nothing:

```
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)        
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill;
```

All that does is create a new player layer and throw it away.

The AVPlayerViewController already has a player layer! Set the video gravity of the AVPlayerViewController.

```
    controller.videoGravity = ...
```